# how to connect rowCountChanged to a slot

Tags: qt, qtablewidget

here is what i tend to design:
   when the tablewidget changes(say its rowcount), 
   the label will show the rowcount.But when i tried it, Qtcreator says: 
  `Object::connect: No such signal QTableWidget::rowCountChanged(int,int) in ..\ui\mainwindow.cpp:55`

why? rowCountChanged(int, int) is one slot inherited from QTableView, i think...

Thanks

Comment: rowCountChanged - no such signal. Where did you get it (link to documentation)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As merlin said, Thats a protected slot.

But you can ask for the underlying model:

(Since widget inherits from tableView which inherits from AbstractView)

```
QAbstractItemModel * QAbstractItemView::model () const
```

And connect to model signals:

```
void QAbstractItemModel::rowsInserted ( const QModelIndex & parent, int start, int end ) [signal]
void QAbstractItemModel::rowsRemoved ( const QModelIndex & parent, int start, int end ) [signal]
```

[Here](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qabstractitemmodel.html#signals) You got all model signals

In fact, there is another way i would explore:

Subclassing QTableWidget, (public) you will have access to that protected slot.

So, creating your own signal:

```
void YourTableWidget::rowCountChanged(int,int)
{
QTableWidget::rowCountChanged(int,int);
emit your_signal(...);

}
```

Comment: @Trompa +1 nice follow up ;O)

Comment: @Trompa  fantastic way

Comment: besides, I find another way.  only 2 ways to change the rows:dele or add.  so in the subroutines, just add your **own signal** like `changeRows(rowCount())`. and connect it to the wanted slots, magic would happen.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the definition of rowCountChanged: -

```
void QTableView::rowCountChanged(int oldCount, int newCount) [protected slot]
```

This is a protected slot, so the error that you're seeing 'No such signal' is correct. What you're probably needing to do is check for a change in the model data that is attached to the QTableView.